# Is a fully normal space even normal?

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Ryzard Engelking in his topology text at the historical and bibliographic notes of $5.1$ says that a topological space $X$ is fully normal if every open cover has an open star refinement (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzMYQ.png) to see original text) but at $3.1$ he defines implicitly (**is it true?**) refinements must be a cover (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbkSH.png) to see original text) so that more explicitly for Engelking a topological space would be fully normal if every open cover has an open-star refinement which is even a cover. Moreover, even Steen and Seebach in the text *Counterexamples in Topology* seem to proceed just as Engelking: see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4hN.png) for details. However, on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space#Variations) Wikipedia article is simply written that a topological space is fully normal when every open cover has an open star refinement and is stated that fully normal spaces are normal.

So on [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fully_T4_Space_is_T4_Space) WikiProof page it is proved that an *Engelking* fully normal space is normal and this proof requires that the open star refinement **must** be a cover so that I thought to put a question where I ask to prove or disprove if a *Wiki* fully normal space is normal. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Whenever we talk about a cover refinement, then (implicitly or not) it is always a cover.

Comment: @freakish Okay, so (for confirmation) the wiki definition requires that the (open-star) refinement is a cover, right?

Comment: Yes, and if you go the [refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)#Refinement) definition you will see that wiki also says it is a cover. I.e. it is a part of defintion, we don't consider refinements that are not covers, you will not see such thing.

Comment: @freakish Perfect, thanks for the new reference! :-)

Comment: As freakish said, refinements of covers are always required to be covers again. Dropping this requirement would not make much sense. For example, each one-element subset of the given cover would be a refinement.

Comment: @PaulFrost Perfect, thanks for your the information!!! :-)